# Text of Button Widget not Appearing when Button Dimensions Change

Tags: python, button, text, tkinter, widget

I want to create buttons with specific dimensions, with text in them.
Most smaller buttons do not display text, no matter the size of text used.

See the example below:

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
frame = Frame(main, width = 200, height = 40)
frame.pack()
button_list = []
for i in range(5):
    button_list.append(Button(frame, height = 40, width = 40, text = str(i)))
    button_list[i].place(x = i * 40, y = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button `width` parameter is in the number of characters -- not pixels -- when you use text instead of an image on a button.

You are creating buttons that are 40 *characters* wide. However, you are placing them 40 *pixels* apart. Since tkinter will center the text on the buttons by default, each button is covering up the text of the button before it.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Bryan Oakley's answer, you can specify the width / height of the buttons in pixels inside `place`:

```
for i in range(5):
    button_list.append(Button(frame, text = str(i)))
    button_list[i].place(x=i * 40, y=0, width=40, height=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm) tutorial the `Button` height and width are specified in `text lines` for text buttons, whereas your frame dimension is specified in `pixels`. So you should change your button definition to something like:

```
for i in range(5):
    button_list.append(Button(frame, height = 1, width = 5, text = str(i)))        
    button_list[i].place(x = i * 40, y = 0)
```

This will produce the following output:

[image]